# Discord.js bot doesn't have permissions but it does

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, replit

This is my code:
 `await message.member.timeout(spamTimeout, 'Recieved a timeout for exceeding max message limit.');`
It gives me an error saying:

> DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

But the bot is the owner of the guild so why would it not have permissions?

Comment: I don't think that is possible for a bot to be the owner of a guild. What it might have tried to do is to timeout someone with a role higher than its which caused the error

Comment: Probably tried to timeout someone with the same highest role as the bot or a higher role. Or tried to timeout the actual owner. @Caladan yea lol it's actually possible, try client.guilds.create

Comment: What is the output of this code? `console.log(<Guild>.me.permissions.bitfield);` (Replace <Guild> with the guild the bot owns)

Comment: @Caladan I would just like to notify you that a bot can be the owner of a guild. Sorry for late reply, my stack overflow was not allowing me to comment (with a script error in the browser console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this myself, the problem was the member I was trying to timeout had `ADMINISTRATOR`, but you can't be timed out if you have `ADMINISTRATOR`.

> Also I would just like to tell everyone that a bot can be the owner of
> a guild. Check guild.create();